# What are all the error will come when i change assemblyversion="1.0.0.0" instead of assemblyversion="1.0.*"

Tags: asp.net

What are all the error will come when i change assemblyversion="1.0.0.0" instead of assemblyversion="1.0.*"

1) Is there any problem will come while converting .net framework 4.0 to later

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking, but in general, the effect of differences in assembly version numbers depends on how the assembly is referenced.

If you add a reference to an assembly, and configure the setting `Specific version` to `True` for the reference, it should give you an error or a warning when compiling the project. If you set `Specific version` to `False`, this should not be a problem (that is, assuming the referenced version of the assembly does contain the classes and methods, etc. that are called form the code that uses the assembly).